# Cloud Build - Credentials error using exec wrapper to connect to Cloud SQL Proxy + other GCP resources

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I'm attempting to use the `exec-wrapper` in a Cloud Build step to run the Cloud SQL Proxy and run a Node script to do a custom database migration. Here is what my cloud build config looks like:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api-stg', '.']
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api-stg']
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 'app-stg.yaml', '--image-url=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api-stg']
- name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
  args: ["-i", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api-stg",
         "-s", "$PROJECT_ID:us-central1:<Cloud SQL Instance Name>",
         "--", "scripts/management/custom_migration"]

images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api-stg']
timeout: 1200s # 20 minutes
```

And in my `custom_migration.js` file I have things like:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket(BUCKET_NAME);
const file = await bucket.file(key);
const result = await new Promise(resolve => file.download((err, data) => {...}));
...
```

This causes the following error from the `google-auth-library`:

```
Error: The file at /root/.google/credentials does not exist, or it is not a file. 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/.google'
```

My App Engine Flexible environment is able to run this code when deployed in a new version, but the same code in a Cloud Build step isn't credentialed correctly. How can I allow the exec-wrapper to use the default credentials of my App Engine Flexible environment?

Comment: Why do you need an exec-wrapper here?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I need an exec-wrapper in order to connect to my Cloud SQL instance through the Cloud SQL proxy. It appears that that's the purpose of the exec wrapper

Comment: Ok, you need a Cloud SQL connexion and nodeJS environment to run your migration script, correct? If I have the correct answer, I will also explain you the issue with exec-wrapper and Cloud Build metadata server.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes that's correct!

Comment: Is the script `scripts/management/custom_migration` in your container `gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api-stg` or is it outside?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it's inside the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This step works for me

```
steps:
  - name: 'node:14-alpine'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
        chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
        ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-project-id:us-central1:vertx=tcp:5432 &
        npm install @google-cloud/storage pg
        node index-test.js
```

Because I don't know the content of your custom container, you can try to adapt something like this

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api-stg'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
        chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
        ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-project-id:us-central1:vertx=tcp:5432 &
        npm install @google-cloud/storage pg
        node scripts/management/custom_migration
```

---

About the issue with the standard library, my supposition is a conflict between the AppEngine environment and the Cloud Build environment.

If you have a look to the Google Auth library, you can see a case for App Engine credentials, and another one for Compute credentials. The compute is used in standard on any Google Cloud services (Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, Compute Engine, Cloud Build,...) but App Engine has its specificities.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, let me try this and get back to you!